# How do I mock java.io.FileOutputStream with Powermockito when it is created by Log4j?

Tags: java, junit, log4j, mockito, powermock

The goal is to have a functional test for a hard coded log4j Appender that extends RollingFileAppender where I can reproduce several instances of a log4j logger writing to the same file using MyAppender. My approach was to intercept the creation of the FileOutputStream created by log4j's FileAppender class.

But the System.out calls in the anonymous Answers never get called. When I put a break-point on FileOutputStream constructors I see that it is being created exactly as I expect, with the arguments I specify below. When I put a break-point on the write methods, it is the three arg version that is being called.

I'm using meterware's ServletUnit to simulate being in a container. MyLogAppender.logFile is a constant.

What am I missing?

```
@Test
@PrepareForTest({MyLogAppender.class})
public void MyLogMessageGetsWritten() throws SAXException, IOException, Exception {
    //...
    // INTERCEPT LOG HERE SOMEHOW
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileOutputStream.class);
    FileOutputStream mockFos = PowerMockito.mock(FileOutputStream.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(FileOutputStream.class).withParameterTypes(String.class, boolean.class).withArguments(MyLogAppender.logFile, true).thenReturn(mockFos);        
    //...
    PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            Object mock = invocation.getMock();
            System.out.println("write(byte[], int, int) Called with " + args);
            return args;
        }
    }).when(mockFos).write(any(byte[].class), anyInt(), anyInt());
    //...
    // ASSERT LOG SUCCESS HERE

}
```

P.S. I am running with PowerMockRunner even though I didn't paste that part.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your application code, it's difficult to be sure exactly what to suggest.  But can you just mock the log4j `Logger`?  Just inject a mock of the `Logger` and verify that the right log methods are being called on it.

If you mock the `FileOutputStream` instead, then you are actually testing log4j as well as testing your own application code.  Unless you are on the development team for log4j, you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: The functional test was to reproduce the log duplication when multiple Loggers are inheriting from a parent all within a single container. It was a log4j misunderstanding that caused the duplication in the first place but by attempting to write the test I do understand log4j a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: eliminate the use of ServletUnit/HttpUnit because they got in the way. I don't know if it was the static initialization or private scope of some stuff or both, but when I got rid of the fake container and just instantiated the bare classes I needed it worked.